# How to save all Data, Registry and supporting settings for my Visual Studio before I format my system

Tags: visual-studio, operating-system, filesystems

I would want to format my Windows 8 Laptop.
But before I do that, I would want to ensure that I would not be expected to reconfigure all settings of VS2013 from scratch in my format fresh laptop. 
I have been given a shared folder to make all relevant saves (of actual VS projects ) before I give my system for format.
Can someone please help as to how I can achieve this in a simple manner.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Use "Tools\Import and Export settings", and export all settings. After you reinstalled visual studio, just import the saved settings.